# How to test function in private scope?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am not able to assert function `selectXHandler`, when i try to test it directly. Since it's defined in the private scope. I can't mock or spy on this function because you can't access it

```
export const CheckboxWrapper = ({
  x,
  y,
  z,
  a = [],
}: CheckboxWrapperProps) => {
  const State = useContext(Context);
  const [state, dispatch] = State;
  const { Items } = state;

  const selectXHandler = () => {
    const payload = {
      x,
      a,
    };
    dispatch({ type: action, payload });
  };

  if (y) {
    return (
      <div className="mt5">
        <Checkbox
          checked={selectedItems[x] !== undefined}
          label={z}
          onChange={selectXHandler}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

```
    const selectXHandler = jest.fn();
    await fireEvent.click(checkbox);
    expect(checkbox).toBeChecked();

    expect(selectXHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

I am getting following error:

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: you should test public-facing behavior and not internal implementation details. E.g. test how your UI elements change, not what internal functions get called

Comment: im looking at integration testing, and checking if function is triggered or not is part of that. @bsapaka

Comment: you can mock redux instead and check if its dispatch has been called and with what arguments. It's also your component "public interface", unlike some prviatefunction inside. Assume, you renamed your internal function - may application be broken because of it? no. On the other side, if your component starts to dispatch action "A" instead of "B" it may break your app. So it makes sense cover that with tests.

Comment: @contextq regardless of what kind of test it is, it should always test the public contract, not internal implementation. You should be able change any internals in a way that satisfies the correct behavior, and the test should still pass.

Comment: @skyboyer im not using redux, instead using usereducer and context to create something similar. Can you suggest in pseudo code how this would be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has discussed in comments above, it's bad move to test some internals. Imagine that's possible, we renamed that internal function or inline it or split into two. Will our test that tests it fail? Definitely. Will our app be broken? Certainly not.

We should be bound to public interface. For component public interface is:

1. `import`s(like input values)
2. props(also input value)
3. render result(output value)
4. contexts if any used(also let's treat as input value)

So I see test in next way:

1. for some input props
2. we simulate click on Checkbox
3. and verify that `dispatch` from context has been called with some desired argument.

I don't know RTL enough so my sample will be about Enzyme. But I'm sure it will be easy to translate it into appropriate RTL selector queries.

```
import Context from '../where/its/placed/someContext.js'; 


it('dispatch is called with A on checkbox is clicked', () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  const state = {}; // or some initial state your test requires

  const ourComponent = mount(<Content.Provider value={{ dispatch, state }}>
    <CheckboxWrapper {...somePropsYouNeed} /></Content.Provider>);
  ourComponent.find({label: 'some-label'}).simulate('change');

  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: 'someType', payload: 'somePayload' });
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: *it's bad move to test some internals* - it's not, this depends on the case. It's bad for functional components because they just weren't designed for that. I often see that "test the behaviour not implementation" is treated as religious dogma, and that's a really bad move IMO. *Will our test that tests it fail? Definitely. Will our app be broken? Certainly not* - why is it a bad thing? Many times better than tests that don't fail when the app is broken. If you lose hours on fixing tests that shouldn't fail, that's bad. If asserting the internals saves you hours of debugging, that's good. YMMV

Comment: @EstusFlask engineering is always about compromises, agree with you. But if beginner developer binds themselves to testing internals right from the start, they will end up with both: unreliable tests _and_ wasting time on maintenance because of fragility. Also for point "why is it a bad thing?" - because(depending on case, for sure) it makes refactoring almost impossible. Few people like pain and most just skip refactoring they could do if having to update 10+ tests to satisfy lift-up-state or move-method-into-shared-helper refactoring.

Comment: @EstusFlask actually my sample above is also a compromise(and I realize that) and rely on internals partially(internals of how `Context` works, assertion against `dispatch`'s arguments). The fully internal-independent would be rather integrational and will render `<Provider><CheckboxWrapper /><AnotherComponentThatConsumesContext /></Provider>` when we trigger things on `Checkbox` and verify if _another_ component is changed accordingly.